# Why custom messages are not appearing?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code to send an email. The subject and message fields are required. But if the user dont fill this fields and clicks in "Send" it appears:

```
The subject field is required.
The message field is required.
```

Instead of appear the custom messages:

```
The field subject is mandatory to send email.
The field message is mandatory to send email.
```

Do you know what can be the issue?

```
public function contactOrganizer($id, Request $request){
        $conference = Conference::find($id);


        $rules = [
            'subject' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required',
        ];


        $customMessages = [
            'subject' => 'The field subject is mandatory to send email.',
            'message' => 'The field message is mandatory to send email.',
        ];


        $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);

        $message = $request->message;
        $subject = $request->subject;

        Mail::to($conference->organizer_email)
        ->send(new UserNotification
        ($conference, $message, $subject));
    }
```

The $rules shows:

```
array:2 [▼
  "subject" => "required"
  "message" => "required"
]
```

The $customMessages shows:

```
array:2 [▼
  "subject" => "The field subject is mandatory to send email."
  "message" => "The field message is mandatory to send email."
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, change the code to this. You need to add .required to the field name. Or whatever property you are trying to display custom messages for.

```
$customMessages = [
            'subject.required' => 'The field subject is mandatory to send email.',
            'message.required' => 'The field message is mandatory to send email.',
        ];
```